# while loop calling array outside

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

Ill start again and thank you all for replying.

I have a log file, and i take the entry and remove all rubbish from it.
the array or list i am left with is this

```
23
23.23.23.23
45
45.45.45.45
100
34.34.54.13
```

how i call each line i want is with this.

```
a = 1
while a < 18:
    a = a + 2
    #logging.debug(line.split(PID_ANDROID)[a])
    countIP = a
    trySomething()

    if a == 20:
        break
```

but i have to do things after i call it.
i want to be able to use the first entry,

```
> do something 
> see if something is happening
> if its not goto 3rd entry
> try the same thing again.
```

this is what I am stuck on.
because when I call it from inside something else and I use global to store.
python tells me I cant us a str or turp. or with code below gives me a continues output of everything in the list.

atm i have this code.

```
def trySomething():
global countIP
global LOG_SPLITER
#logging.debug('Processing Number: %s' % (countIP,))
logging.debug(LOG_SPLITER.split(PID_ANDROID)[countIP])
time.sleep(.5)
clearScreen()
#grabBox90()
#lineGoto()
```

my question is.
how can i do the loop, and pull out only one at a time to do something with it, and when i get to a finished loop goto the next one?

Comment: `c = + 2` is not valid Python, I also recommend you start using things like `x+=1` instead of `x = x + 1`.

Comment: This post really needs to be refined so that you're presenting a clear problem and question. As it stands, it seems more like rambling about what you're working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if you should use a for loop with an initial index of 1 and a step size of 2. Alternatively, use the explicit debug statement for value 1 and then loop over the rest, starting at 3, to avoid the if test. If the remainder of the code is to increment by 1 instead of 2, then that allows you to do the initial skip properly while still having the loop.

Instead of

```
c = 1
#do my stuff
while c < 20:
    if c == 1:
        logging.debug(line.split(PID_ANDROID)[c])
        c = + 2
    else:
        logging.debug('Moving on to a refresh')
    # You do not incremennt c
    # c += 2 should go here to increment every time
```

Python 2

```
for i in xrange(1,20,2):
  # do your processing
```

Python 3

```
for i in range(1,20,2):
  # do you processing
```

Comment: Perfect reference, i added my code inside my loop and moved everything else outside.

Comment: Code works, And for everyone that wanted to know what i was trying to achieve is this.    a = 1
    while a < 20:
        if a == 1:
            logging.debug(line.split(PID_ANDROID)[a])
            ip = os.popen(adbInput + line.split(PID_ANDROID)[a])
            a = + 2
            ip.close()
            ip = os.popen(adbTap + '56 584')  # tap scan
            ip.close()
            time.sleep(3)
            grabBox90()

        if a == 20:
            break

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to log every entry in `line` you could do:

```
entries = line.split(PID_ANDROID)
for e in entries[::2]:  # take every other element
    logging.debug(e)
```

Iterating over the entries is "more pythonic".

Comment: Since he explicitly debugs on `c==1` and skips all the rest, this is not what he is asking for.